# Echo in command Prompt if there is no response

Tags: windows, cmd

I am using the following command:

```
netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state | findstr ON
```

For example If I run this command in my window command prompt there are 2 possibilities:

1. There will be no result
2. There will be some thing printed on screen

What I want in case nothing found I want to echo something for instance nothing found on the command prompt as response of the above command instead of nothing.

I want to do this in one line instead of writing a script.

Comment: `netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state | (findstr ON || Echo Not On)`

Comment: Are you saying that there are times when `%__AppDir__%netsh.exe AdvFirewall Show AllProfiles State` outputs nothing at all? If so is it because the firewall is turned off for all profiles? I would have expected it to still output `OFF` against each if that was the case. The only scenario, I'd expect otherwise was possibly if the firewall service itself was off/disabled, _(even then why use `AllProfiles` over `CurrentProfile`?)_, and even in that case I'd have expected a message telling me that it was off or couldn't be started. Can you please explain the scenario you're trying to detect?